# .bash_logout is not running on exit of putty

Tags: bash, logout

I have some script on `.bash_logout` file. That script is running when a user is logging out using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or using `exit` command. If someone directly close putty application instead of logging out from the system, then `.bash_logout` is not running.

Can anyone help me how to run `.bash_logout` even if someone close putty application without log out from the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added below function and a trap in .bashrc. The trap will trigger the function `exit_session` when the shell will get `SIGHUP` signal.

```
exit_session() {
    . "$HOME/.bash_logout"
}
trap exit_session SIGHUP
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't do. `.bash_logout` contents will be executed only with `exit`, `logout` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, means, explicitly exit the shell.  If you close the terminal emulator, processes are sent `SIGHUP`, and bash doesn’t run `~/.bash_logout`.

[`bash(1)` manpage:](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> When a login shell exits, `bash` reads and executes commands from the
>   files `~/.bash_logout` and `/etc/bash.bash_logout`, if the files exists.

Best you can do is to [adapt this solution](https://superuser.com/a/410534/210242) to map an script with the `trap` command.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a trap with `SIGHUP` signal